# Dynamically create arbitrary objects for unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Our codebase is filled with domain objects with large numbers of numeric and string fields.  In my unit tests, I find myself manually creating instances of these different objects like so:

```
var car1 = new Car();
car1.Make = "Make1";
car1.Model = "Model1";
car1.Year = 1;

var car2 = new Car();
car2.Make = "Make2";
car2.Model = "Model2";
car2.Year = 2;
```

etc..

What's the cleanest way to generically build objects of any type automatically with only a single function call?

Keep in mind I don't want the fields to be generated with random values.  Arbitrary repeatable values (like the 1 and 2 above) are what I'm going for.

Comment: We donßt know much about your objects and their members except the little information you gave. In particular we don´t know what you mean bby arbitrary but not random. I doubt there´s much for us to guess here.

Comment: What more information do you want about the objects?  This is meant to be used for any type of object that has a lot of numeric and string fields as I mentioned.

Comment: If you don't know the difference between arbitrary and random, see this: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-arbitrary-and-random

I'm simply saying I don't want randomly generated values, because I want the unit tests to be completely deterministic and repeatable.  The values '1' and '2' in the question are still arbitrary in that they weren't specifically chosen for any reason.

Comment: Well, if you want *repeadable* values, you have to *determine* those values. How should anyone know what you consider a valid value? What is with `"Model3"` for example? Is this valid? We don´t know and thus there´s no way for us to create any generic method. There´s simply too less information for a *generic* solution.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture

Comment: @HimBromBeere again - they are arbitrary.  The specific values don't matter for the test case.  Any non-arbitrary values would obviously have to be decided by the tester.

Answer (score 0):

I ending up opting for a generic method that uses reflection to automatically do what the question is showing done manually.  Any field created this way can be overwritten and any complex types will have to be set manually.  Bools are just set to true.  I'm curious to hear people's thoughts on doing it this way.  It saves me a TON of time and effort as I'm building unit tests.

Here's how my tests end up looking (simple example without complex types or string/numeric fields that I want to overwrite with specific values, though those are handled as well):

```
[Test]
public void TestCreateCars()
{
    // Arrange
    var expectedCars = new List<Car>();
    expectedCars.Add(TestUtils.CreateObject<Car>(1));
    expectedCars.Add(TestUtils.CreateObject<Car>(2));
    expectedCars.Add(TestUtils.CreateObject<Car>(3));

    // using moq but anything could be used
    _carService.Setup(x => x.GetNewCarsInfo()).Returns(cars);

    var carsFactory = new carFactory(_carService);

    // Act
    var cars = carsFactory.CreateCars();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(3, cars.Count);
    TestUtils.AssertObjectDefaultFields(cars[0], 1);
    TestUtils.AssertObjectDefaultFields(cars[1], 2);
    TestUtils.AssertObjectDefaultFields(cars[2], 3);

    _carService.VerifyAll();
}
```

The method that creates an object:

```
// Use this to instantiate objects of types with a large number of int/string fields for testing.  You can override any values after calling this - complex fields won't be set
//  -sets numeric values on that object to its 'id'
//  -sets string values on that object to the name of the field concatenated with the 'id'
public static T CreateObject<T>(int id)
{
    var instance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

    // only set properties with a visible setter
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.GetSetMethod() != null);

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var type = property.PropertyType;
        if (IsNumeric(type))
        {
            type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) ?? type;
            var value = Convert.ChangeType(id, type);

            property.SetValue(instance, value);
        }
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            property.SetValue(instance, property.Name + id);
        }
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
        {
            property.SetValue(instance, true);
        }
    }

    return instance;
}
```

A method that asserts objects created that way have the expected values:

```
// Use this to assert that an object created by CreateObject<T> has all of the 'default' values:
//  -numeric values equal its 'id'
//  -string values equal the name of the field concatenated with the 'id'
// 
// unsetProperties: property names that we want to assert are their default values
// ignoreProperties: property names that we don't want to assert anything against - we should assert against these outside of this method
public static void AssertObjectDefaultFields<T>(T obj, int id, HashSet<string> unsetProperties = null, HashSet<string> ignoreProperties = null)
{
    // only test properties with a visible setter, otherwise it wouldnt have been set
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.GetSetMethod() != null);
    unsetProperties = unsetProperties ?? new HashSet<String>();
    ignoreProperties = ignoreProperties ?? new HashSet<String>();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if(!ignoreProperties.Contains(property.Name))
        {
            if (unsetProperties.Contains(property.Name))
            {
                var defaultValue = property.PropertyType.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType) : null;
                Assert.AreEqual(defaultValue, property.GetValue(obj));
            }
            else if (IsNumeric(property.PropertyType))
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(id, property.GetValue(obj));
            }
            else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(property.Name + id, property.GetValue(obj));
            }
            else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(true, property.GetValue(obj));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For testing if a field's type is numeric:

```
private static bool IsNumeric(Type type)
{
    var NumericTypes = new HashSet<Type>
    {
        typeof(int),  typeof(double),  typeof(decimal),
        typeof(long), typeof(short),   typeof(sbyte),
        typeof(byte), typeof(ulong),   typeof(ushort),
        typeof(uint), typeof(float)
    };

    return NumericTypes.Contains(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) ?? type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a domain object, why not using a factory ?

An unit test should be valid whatever the values you set.

If you want to test for a specific value, you should write a specific test.

Or may be your need is different ?

Comment: I don't want to implement a factory for every object type that's ever instantiated in my code.

Comment: Specific values that I need to test for would obviously have to be set up specifically, but for fields whose values are arbitrary for the sake of the test, it takes a long time to manually instantiate without adding much value.  The question is how to best set up those arbitrary values without all the work to instantiate them.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are asking for a framework that populates test data. There're many great libraries such as:

- [NBuilder](https://github.com/nbuilder/nbuilder)
- [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture)
- [Bogus](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus)